# Does anyone know why there's a weird symbol in place of the 1 in this comment?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, comments

The comment at [Sum of strings without converting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41833/sum-of-strings-without-converting/41840#comment97724_41846) displays strangely on Firefox 33.1 on OSX 10.9.5.  Look at the numeral `1` inside the parens in `each_cons(10)`.

Any idea why?

What is that character that got in there?

[image]

Comment: no-repro. Try in Chrome.

Comment: not Chrome.  Yes in FF34.  It's actually not a bug, though... it's an extra character that I can't seem to find anywhere else.  Maybe this is a Mozilla bug.  I'll turn this into discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the HTML:

[image: html]

As you can see, a `&zwnj;&#8203;` was automatically inserted by the Stack Exchange software. [This has been reported on The Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970/180276) (and the reason was provided by @TimStone in the comments on that question).

Seeing as I don't see the symbol on Chromium or Firefox on Ubuntu or the app on Android, it's probably a font problem.

As further evidence, the comment I've posted below should have the same strange character in it for you.

Comment: this is a `teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest`

Comment: You're icy Doorknob now?

Comment: @NotthatCharles Indeed; see my profile "about me" section. ;)

Comment: Planning on becoming "Doorknob 花" in the Spring?

Comment: or "Doorknob 嚏" more likely (`sneeze`, not `flower`)?

Comment: Now I feel you are more like "Doorknob 霜" (a kind of 冰).